# Error compiling structures with emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have the following code compiled with em++:

```
struct Point6f{
float x0;
float y0;
float z0;
float x1;
float y1;
float z1;
};

struct containerBbox {
float x0;
float y0;
float z0;
float x1;
float y1;
float z1;
};

containerBbox createBbox(Point6f);

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_value_example) {
emscripten::value_array<Point6f>("Point6f")
            .element(&Point6f::x0)
            .element(&Point6f::y0)
            .element(&Point6f::z0)
            .element(&Point6f::x1)
            .element(&Point6f::y1)
            .element(&Point6f::z1);

emscripten::value_object<containerBbox>("containerBox")
            .field("x0", &containerBbox::x0)
            .field("y0", &containerBbox::y0)
            .field("z0", &containerBbox::z0)
            .field("x1", &containerBbox::x1)
            .field("y1", &containerBbox::y1)
            .field("z1", &containerBbox::z1)
            ;

function("createBbox", &createBbox);
}
```

And I'm getting the following compilation error:

> error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
>       function("createBbox", &createBbox);

Don't mind the redundancy between the definitions of Point6f and containerBbox, those are irrelevant, I didn't even manage to get the example of the emscripten page to work (see: https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#value-types), so I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `value_obj` needing a namespace, you need to put `emscripten::` in front of `function`. Otherwise the compiler thinks you are declaring a C++ function called `function` without giving it a return type.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was it! :)